# Handling binary literal in python

Tags: python, binary, hex

I am trying to translate code from php to python. I have a list of binary literals -

```
['0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b100', '0b1001100']
```

This is equal to `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010001001100` when concatenated.

```
int("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010001001100",2)
```

gives `1100`

How do i make this from the list. Unable to concatenate binary literals.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `1001001100` when concatenated?

Comment: Unstated here is that each piece represents eight bits, and may be missing leading zeros.

Comment: 0b0 = 00000000 , last two 00000100 , 01001100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> l = ['0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b100', '0b1001100']
>>> int("".join("%02x" % int(x,0) for x in l), 16)
1100
```

Python understand `0b0101` as a binary literal, so I use `int('0b0101', 0)` to convert each piece to an int.  Then I format it in a convenient format (two digits of hex), concatenate them, and interpret them as a hex integer.

Comment: Where is `int(..., 0)` documented? Never seen it before.

Comment: Right there in the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int   "Base 0 means to interpret the string exactly as an integer literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8, 10, or 16."

Answer (score 1):

You need the zfill method to pad your elements with the right quantity of zeros

```
li = ['0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b100', '0b1001100']
zero_padded = [x[2:].zfill(8) for x in li]
print ''.join(zero_padded)
```

Outputs

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010001001100
```

Answer (score 0):

Just strip off the `0b`:

```
binary = ''.join(x[2:] for x in yourlist)
print binary
print int(binary, 2)
```

Comment: Outputs 588. I need to concatenate and get the ascii value

Comment: @AdityaSingh: Your expected output is wrong. You've added a zero somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ugly enough for you:

```
int(''.join([i for sl in [s[2:].zfill(8) for s in l] for i in sl]),2)
```

(It seems to work.)

Maybe this is more readable:

```
l = ['0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b0', '0b100', '0b1001100']
n = 0
for s in l:
    n = n*256 + int(s,2)
print n
```